# C#. split identificator on the words

Tags: c#, regex

I have some identificator. For example: 'basicHtmlConverter.' 
I need split his on the some words: 'basic Html Converter'. 
I think to using `Regex.Split` with some pattern.

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Some details: there are strings that contains a composite words - 'baseAdapter', 'canClearScene' etc. I need C# code that will be split this strings to: 'base Adapeter', 'can Clear Scene' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a regexp: you just need to scan the string once and LINQ your way through the task.

```
yourString.Select(c => string.Format(Char.IsUpper(c) ? " {0}" : "{0}", c));
```

This will hand you a `IEnumerable<string>` object containing all the data you need, which can become what you need like this:

```
string[] output = string.Split(" ", string.Join("", yourString.Select(c => string.Format(Char.IsUpper(c) ? " {0}" : "{0}", c)));
```

Basically, flow goes like this:

- Insert any space needed
- Pack up data
- Split the tokens

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Regex`:

```
([a-z]+)([A-Z]?[a-z]*)+
```

and your code should be like this:

```
var nameList = new List<string>();
var inputString = "canClearScene";
foreach (Capture capture in Regex.Matches(inputString, "(?<name>[a-z]+)(?<name>[A-Z]?[a-z]*)+")[0].Groups["name"].Captures)
{
    nameList.Add(capture.Value);
}
```

or in `LINQ` way:

```
var nameList = (from Capture capture in Regex.Matches(inputString, "(?<name>[a-z]+)(?<name>[A-Z]?[a-z]*)+")[0].Groups["name"].Captures
                select capture.Value).ToList();
```